# Converting a line from a firewall on OpenBSD 4.9 to OpenBSD 4.7

Tags: firewall, openbsd, pf

What is the OpenBSD 4.7 equivalent of this line from OpenBSD 4.9 for use with pf?

```
no nat on egress proto udp from 192.168.1.10 port 4672 to any
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your previous rules were something like this:

```
nat on egress from 192.168.1.0/24 -> (egress)
no nat on egress proto udp from 192.168.1.10 port 4672 to any
```

an example of doing this with the new rules would be

```
match out on egress proto udp from 192.168.1.10 port 4672 tag NONAT
match out on egress from 192.168.1.0/24 !tagged NONAT nat-to (egress)
```